# Add minutes to time

Tags: php

I have the following code

```
$time = "12:00";
$duration = 90 . " minutes";
$arrival = strtotime("+" . $duration, $time);
```

Output should be `13:30`.

I get the following error: "A non well formed numeric value encountered in" (line with `$arrival`)

What can I do?

Comment: Pro tip: write your code in english.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code should work:

```
$time = strtotime("12:00");
$duration = "+90 minutes";
$arrival = strtotime($duration, $time);
print(date("H:i", $arrival));
```

Demo: https://eval.in/95328

Read more about [Unix timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) and the PHP function [strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime).

Answer (score 1):

Consider using PHP DateTime and DateInterval classes, like this:

```
$time = new \DateTime('now');
$time->add( new \DateInterval('PT90M') );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This Simple code :

```
<?php $time = strtotime('12:00');
$more = date("H:i", strtotime('+90 minutes', $time)); ?>
```